# Do any standard, built-in USB drivers give the USB device full access to system memory?

Tags: windows, usb, security, drivers

I am wondering if a USB device could potentially be a security hole on a properly configured system just by being plugged in. This was inspired by [a post on BitLocker](https://msmvps.com/blogs/alunj/archive/2006/09/26/Is-BitLocker-Misdirected_3F00_.aspx), namely the phrase:

> USB devices, after all, get direct access to the system's memory

As far as I know, USB devices don't *literally* have such access - right? But I can imagine a driver that gives a USB device such an ability.

Are any standard USB device drivers, shipped with Win7, known to expose arbitrary physical memory locations to the USB device?

Comment: I'm almost sure that only Firewire and Thunderbolt devices get such access.

Comment: I cannot imagine that such a flaw exists, as it would be very major and very simple. Poor proof I know but...

Comment: @DrMcKay so could a specially crafted Thunderbolt device read all the physical memory in a system? Or only a subset of it that was reserved specifically for this purpose, wiped of any potentially sensitive previous data?

Comment: @romkyns Memory access is totally unrestricted. And yes, it's a whole memory.  
Mac: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/02/24/thunderbolt_mac_threat/ and Windows: http://www.friendsglobal.com/papers/FireWire%20Memory%20Dump%20of%20Windows%20XP.pdf (it's about Firewire as I have no idea if Windows supports Thunderbolt). In fact, both protocols give any device a blind trust.

Comment: I'm pretty sure most USB drivers run in user-mode now, so the whole physical memory access issue is non-existent.  I'm writing some USB drivers right now actually, and don't see how I could gain access to anything until my device is initialized by some software.  However, even if I were to have that ability, being in user-mode would just BSOD the system before anything happened.

Comment: USB devices don't have access to anything, they are peripheral slave devices.The USB host controller, however, operates solely on running memory accesses processing linked lists. The only way for a USB device to do a harm is if you autoexecute some malicious software stored in USB drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most USB drivers run in [user-mode under the WDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463301) driver framework, so the whole physical memory access issue is non-existent. There is no place in USB drivers that allow direct access to anything in memory.  Regardless, if a device driver does attempt to access memory it should not, Windows will blue-screen most of the time.

It is worth noting that if a device is given enough permissions, exploits can be created (i.e. buffer overflows) through the *software* that accesses that device.

TLDR:  USB drivers themselves don't pose a threat, but the software you use with the device can.